# How to prove that $\forall a \forall b \exists x(a+x=b \lor b+x=a)$

Tags: proof-writing, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

The universe is the set of natural numbers including 0, defined by the Peano Axioms. I tried and failed to prove this by induction on b.

Comment: For induction on $b$ you have to prove $\forall a \exists x (a+x=b \lor b+x=a)$. The base case for $b=0$ amounts to: $0+a=a$ and thus $(a+x=0 \lor 0+a=a)$ and thus $\exists x (a+x=0 \lor 0+x=a)$.

Comment: The induction step is: assume $∀a∃x(a+x=b ∨ b+x=a)$ and prove $∀a∃x(a+x=sb ∨ sb+x=a)$. I think you have to prove it by induction on $a$.